# How many total number of processes are there?

Tags: operating-system, fork

Yesterday, i had a interview and i was asked this question of code snippet using fork() .

```
void main()
{............
for (int k=1;k<=10;k++)
{
pid[k]=fork();
if(!pid[k])
execvp(.....);
}
}
```

According to my understanding, i told 1024 total processes will be there including the parent as 2^n -1 = 1023 + 1 parent where n = total forks

But, the interviewer replied that my answer was wrong.

**What is wrong with my understanding?**

Comment: Is the program that gets executed by execvp this same program, or something unrelated? It might also help to know why you think 1024 is the correct answer (ie, explain your reasoning)

Comment: I think child gets replaced with different program .?

Comment: Well, in that case the child processes won't take part in further forking, which will lead to 10 children and 1 parent, no? Also, 2^10-1 definitely isn't 1024...

Comment: please post it as an answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this code

```
pid[k]=fork();
if(!pid[k])
    execvp(.....);
```

and reading [the man page of fork](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) which states that

> On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent,
>          and 0 is returned in the child.

we know that the child process will perform the exec call (and go on executing a different program), whereas the parent will loop and create another child.

This means that a child will be created for each iteration of the loop, in this case 10 times. So, the answer is 10 children + 1 parent = 11.

---

Now, if the program that gets started by exec is the same program, the fun will stop only when the computer's memory is exhausted: on every iteration 10 programs will each create 10 children, which each will create 10 children, and so on. A pecularity of fork() is that parent and child get an image of the same variables (which would lead to a predictable number of children, ie some figure related to a power of 2), obviously this isn't true when a program gets exec'd, which means that available memory will be the only limit.

Comment: if execvp() loads the same program, then ?